# WebSphere 6.1 - getting profiling information just from the console

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, profiling, websphere

The situation is like this, we have a very slow WebSphere 6.1 deployment, and want to get information from the console (we can't have access to anything but the console)

What are the tools we have there to troubleshoot (performance issues, memory etc)?

Remember, all we can have is web access to the console web interface

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no control at all from the host, the best you can get is WebSphere's PMI (Performance Monitoring Infrastructure). You can turn on different monitoring switches, including Java or WebSphere resources to have a first glance of what might be current bottleneck.

Comment: How do I get there, and how do I turn it on? (PMI) do I have to restart WebSphere afterwards?
Is there a document describing it for non WebShpere pros?

Comment: Form the console, on the left, find "Monitoring and Tuning". By default, PMI is ON with basic level of metrics. You can change the level on-the-fly (there's a 'Runtime' tab for chanign runtime level without persistence across restart). To see the metrics, under same "Monitoring and Tuning", there's "Performance Viewer". It's not very fancy UI I admit, but you get to select the desired metrics and see it on console.

Google "tivoli performance viewer" should get you a head start on this tool.